# Possible to use custom css when using a Nativescript core theme?

Tags: css, nativescript

i'm busy with a Nativescript app, i'm using the core dark theme but would like to add some font-awesome glyphicons and custom css.  I import the core dark theme in my global app.css but don't seem to be able to do anything more in that file after importing the theme...  I've tried to add page-specific css by adding a component-common.css to a specific page but when I add the styleUrls: [...] declaration to the component declaration I always get a runtime error...  Is it possible at all to use custom css ontop of the core Nativescript  theme?  If so how would I go about it (using css files not inline in the xml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use both a theme and custom CSS files.
For example, check [this sample](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/e2ecde823207d3950250b61b79e10a5a5cbf54c4/app/ui-category/layouts/dock-layout/dock-layout.component.ts#L6) where in the same time theme has been applied to the [top CSS file](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/e2ecde823207d3950250b61b79e10a5a5cbf54c4/app/app.css).

Better check (and/or post) your runtime error - it might show you the reason why the app is throwing. Perhaps due to non-existing paths for your styleeUrls !?

Comment: Thanks @Nick Iliev  I think my issue was excluding module.id and adding the relative instead of absolute path to the css file...